# Polynomial invariance clarification

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Consider a polynomial in $n^2$ variables. We may arrange the variables $A_{ij}$ as a matrix $A=(A_{ij})$ and write $P(A) \in \Bbb C[A_{ij}]$. A polynomial like this is said to be invariant if $P(gAg^{-1})=P(A)$ for all $g \in GL_n(\Bbb C)$.

I think I understand this first sentence that if for example $A =\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$, then $P(A) = P(a,b,c,d) \in \Bbb C[a,b,c,d]$, but the second term $P(gAg^{-1})$ is somewhat confusing to me. If $B = gAg^{-1}$ is the polynomial $P(B)$ going to be an element of $\Bbb C[B_{ij}]$ instead of $\Bbb C[A_{ij}]$? For the first one I'm just identifying $A$ with $\Bbb C^4$, but for the latter I'm not sure what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $g \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, then the entries of the matrix $B = gAg^{-1}$ are linear forms in variables $A_{ij}$. So if we substitute $B_{ij}$ into the polynomial $P$, we still get a polynomial in the same variables $A_{ij}$.

For example, if $P(A)=A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21}$ and $g = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, then
$$B = gAg^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} A_{11}+A_{21} & -A_{11}+A_{12}-A_{21}+A_{22} \\ A_{21} & -A_{21}+A_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$
and $$P(gAg^{-1})=(A_{11}+A_{21})(-A_{21}+A_{22})-(-A_{11}+A_{12}-A_{21}+A_{22})A_{21}=A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21}=P(A)$$

If this happens for all invertible matrices $g \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, then the polynomial $P(A)$ is invariant. Like in our case: $P(A)=\det A$ and $P(gAg^{-1})=\det gAg^{-1}=\det g\cdot det A\cdot \det g^{-1}=\det A$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I understand you correctly when you say that the entries of $B = gAg^{-1}$ are linear forms in variables $A_{ij}$ do you mean that the $A_{ij}$ are some sort of functions and not elements of the underlying field? @vladimir-lysikov

Comment: There are two ways to think about it.

One is closer to the quote from your question: we view $A_{ij}$ simply as variables, and polynomials as expressions containing these variables. So $A$ is a symbolic matrix, and if we want to compute $P(\bar{A})$ on a specific matrix $\bar{A}=(\bar{A}_{ij})\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, we substitute $\bar{A}_{ij}$ in place of variables $A_{ij}$, so that after this substitution $A$ becomes $\bar{A}$.

Comment: The second is to view polynomials directly as functions on matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. In this case polynomial $A_{ij}$ is a function which on a matrix $\bar{A}=(\bar{A}_{ij})\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ takes value $\bar{A}_{ij}$, and entries of $B$ are linear functions in the entries of the original matrix, and the equality $P(A)=P(gAg^{-1})$ means that the polynomials $P(\bar{A})$ and $P(g\bar{A}g^{-1})$ coincide as function on $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$,

These two views differ on finite fields, but over $\mathbb{C}$ you can use whatever feels better to you.

Comment: I see. The distinction between these two is still slightly confusing to me. Is is possible to come up with simple examples of these two notions to see how they differ? @vladimir-lysikov

Comment: As I said, don't worry about it too much. Over infinite fields it's the same, because polynomial is uniquely determined by its values. If you know about finite fields, then, for example, over the fields with 2 elements the polynomial $x^2-x$ is always zero (because $0^2-0=0$ and $1^2-1=0$), and because of that $A_{11}^2-A_{11}$ is not an invariant polynomial, but it represents an invariant function (zero function).